# How to keep cron from stampeding?

Tags: cron

Say I have several cron scripts that need to run every 15 minutes.  I could set them to run: `*/15 * * * *` , but then they all run at the same time.  It seems silly for the server to sit idle for several minutes and then suddenly try to execute a dozen scripts all at the same time.

Is there a way I can have one script run at minute 1, 16, 31, 46 and another at 2, 17, 32, 47?

In other words, I want each script to run every 15 minutes, but I don't care that they run specifically on the quarter hour marks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're making this harder than it needs to be.  Put them all on the same line, separated by semicolons:

```
*/15 * * * * command1 ; command 2 ; command 3
```

It will run `command1`, wait for it to finish, then run `command2`, wait for it to finish, and so on.

Answer (score 16):

If you make your cron job look like this: `6-59/15 * * * *` then it will run at 6, 21, 36 and 51 minutes past the hour.

This may not work with all versions of cron.

Answer (score 15):

You could put all of the scripts into a directory, say `/etc/cron.15m`, and then have cron run

```
*/15 * * * * run-parts /etc/cron.15m
```

That's assuming you have the `run-parts` command.  It's present on all Debian-based systems at least.  It runs all of the executable programs in the named directory, one at a time in list order.

A disadvantage of this method is that if one of the scripts hangs, all the rest will wait and not be executed.  If the run time of all of them is more than 15 minutes, then the job will start running again and you could get a lot of processes piling up.

Comment: `run-parts` is present in Fedora / Red Hat systems too.

Answer (score 9):

The most straightforward way to do this is just to manually set up the commands to run when you want them to:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * command0
1,16,31,46 * * * * command1
2,17,32,47 * * * * command2
...
14,29,44,59 * * * * command14
```

Or you can write a script to automatically generate the appropriate crontab entries (which avoid typos).

Some versions of cron (probably including the one you're using) accept an extended syntax:

```
0-59/15 * * * * command0
1-59/15 * * * * command1
1-59/15 * * * * command2
...
14-59/15 * * * * command14
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron isn't really good at what you're trying to do. Have you considered writing a script that acts as a daemon that basically sleeps 15 minutes, executes the command, then loops?

Comment: There are a couple of potential problems with that.  One is that if you do `sleep 300` between each execution of the command, the command's own execution will cause the time to drift; it might run every 15:10 rather than every 15:00.  And if the background process dies or the system reboots, unlike `crond`, it won't automatically restart.  There are ways to "daemonize" a background process, but then you're pretty much re-implementing `crond`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not a perfect solution (though you could always background the task with &), but there you go.

Comment: Instead, just have cron run a single script that executes all your commands in turn. In fact, it's such a common need that there's a standard script called `run-parts` that ships with most cron installations to do specifically that. See @AndrewSchulman's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many distributions have /etc/cron.d/cronhourly, for which all scripts within get run hourly. You can even specify the order by starting them with sequential numbers, lik 01scriptA 02scriptB - it should be trivial with the cron knowledge you already have to manufacture a "cronhourlybyfour" as we call it on Smoothwall's linux distro base :)

Word of warning: this uses run-parts as previously suggested, and run-parts does NOT like scripts with a . in the name, so don't call it "deletehomefolders.sh" call it "01deletehomefolders" and make sure you start with the right #! line for whatever you intend to interpret your script.